# OrganizationService.Retrieve vs. XrmServiceContext.AccountSet

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am experimenting with retrieving an ActivityPointer 2 ways:

**First way**

```
public Entity GetEntity(NonNullable<string> entityTypeName, Guid entityId)
{
    return
        _organizationService.Retrieve(
            entityTypeName, entityId,
            new ColumnSet(true));
}
```

**Second way**

```
public ActivityPointer GetServiceActivity(Guid entityId)
{
    return _xrmServiceContext.ActivityPointerSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == entityId);
}
```

When passing in the same guid for entityId, **why does the first way return a significantly smaller object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare 2 different objects altogether. The underlying object `Entity` is of the type [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entity.aspx), while the underlying object  `ActivityPointer` is of the type [Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.client.crmentity(v=crm.7).aspx).

One of the reason why `Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntity` has a bigger footprint is because it contains related entity records metadata, which is lazy loaded when you try to access the related entity property. So, the more related entities, the bigger the object, which in this case an `activitypointer` does have.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I would give this answer 1000 points. I've spent so much time trying to find the answer to my question - I'm not so great at finding what I need with documentation - What steps would you have taken to try to research this question?

Comment: @MeggieLuski how were you measuring object size?

Comment: @Nicknow it was just including something called "relatedentities" as well as  "allparts" -- just more objects